# Inserting a row into a Word Table with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have written a program to migrate a set of data from Excel into Word.  The problem is that the format of form in word the must be entered into a new file in a very specific format, with new lines being inserted into the line data. In other words, I have information that is currently held in column two for every row in excel, that now has to be moved into a single row in the sheet I am solving this through adding a row after the table is created in word and then merging them, but the code I found keeps producing the runtime error 4120 Bad parameter.  I am guessing that the code that I am using is actually for use within word not from excel. Any help on the proper code would be appreciated.

```
If section1 = True Then
    'wdDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Add BeforeRow:=.Rows(2)
    wdDoc.Tables.Rows.Add (2)
    With wdDoc.Tables(1)
        .Cell(Row:=2, Column:=2).Merge _
        MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=2, Column:=10)
        .Borders.Enable = False
        wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = "Section I - Authorized Ship Changes"
    End With
Else
End If
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: wdDoc.Tables.Rows.Add (2)

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
wdDoc.Tables.Rows.Add (2)
```

the argument for the `Add` method must be a `Row` object. So something like:

```
wdDoc.Tables.Rows.Add wdDoc.Tables.Rows(2)
```

will add a new row before row 2.
Hope that helps.